# python - extract value from list of dictionary

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, key-value

I need to display book name and calculate average weight of book if the book price is more than 800.
here is my current code, appreciate any help. thank you so much in advance!

```
def calcWeight():
  for book in books:
    for key,value in book.items():
      if key == 'weight':
        if value >= 800:
        totalWeight += value
        avg = totalWeight / 2
        print(avg)

books = [{"name": "textbook", "weight": 500, "price": 800},
          {"name": "notebook", "weight": 100, "price": 200},
          {"name": "storybook", "weight": 700, "price": 1000}]

for book in books:
  for key,value in book.items():
    if key == 'price':
      if value >= 800:
        calcWeight()
```

Comment: You don't need to loop through key in dictionaries. Once you have a book with `for book in books:` you can directly get the price with `book['price']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
books = [{"name": "textbook", "weight": 500, "price": 800},
          {"name": "notebook", "weight": 100, "price": 200},
          {"name": "storybook", "weight": 700, "price": 1000}]


total = 0
length = 0
for book in books:
    if book['price'] >= 800:
        total += book['weight']
        length += 1
average = total / length
print(average)
```

You don't need to loop in a dictionary's key, though. In here, I'm assuming what you mean is that you're getting the average weight of the books if their price is greater than or equal to 800

Comment: thank you so much! this works the best for me as beginner

Comment: @beginnerprogrammer I've updated the code. I put the average outside the loop since you don't really need to update it at every loop if you only need the final average.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way that you can do what you want:

```
def calcWeight(books):
    filtered_elements = [book['weight'] for book in books if book['price'] >= 800] # create a list full of weights for those over the price limit
    return sum(filtered_elements) / len(filtered_elements) # returns the average of all weighted books

books = [{"name": "textbook", "weight": 500, "price": 800},
          {"name": "notebook", "weight": 100, "price": 200},
          {"name": "storybook", "weight": 700, "price": 1000}]

average_weight = calcWeight(books) # store the value from the function
for book in books:
    if book['price'] >= 800: # grab the value from the dictionary and see if it meets our condition
        print(book['name'], average_weight) # print out the name and average
```

Comment: thank you! this code also works for my purpose

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas to create a DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd

books = [{"name": "textbook", "weight": 500, "price": 800},
      {"name": "notebook", "weight": 100, "price": 200},
      {"name": "storybook", "weight": 700, "price": 1000},
      {"name": "whatever", "weight": 500, "price": 1200}]

df = pd.DataFrame(books)
```

Then filter for pricy books:

```
df_pricy = df[df.price>800]
```

Then analyse data:

```
names = list(df_pricy.name)
average_weight = df_pricy.weight.mean()

print("Pricy Books:",names)
print("Average Weight of pricy books",average_weight)
```

Comment: i havent learn panda yet but thank you!

Comment: ---> pip3 install pandas
its worth learning this, since pandas is designed exactly for such tasks